# Авторизация вконтакте на PHP

Tags: вконтакте, php, vkontakte-api

Приветствую

Есть php страница, со следующим содержимым. Код был взят с хэшкода, наверно где то год назад, и работал. Сейчас, сам, почитав справку по API - вроде тоже самое, только авторизоваться не получается. Может кто подсказать, как авторизоваться в вконтакте с помощью апи, по анологии с данным кодом?

```
$name = 'my@mail.ru';
$pass = 'mypass';

$ch = curl_init("https://login.vk.com/?act=login&email=".$name."&pass=".$pass."");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$authoriz = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if(!preg_match('/remixsid=([a-f0-9]{32})/', $authoriz, $sid)){
    echo 'Все плохо';
}else{
    //echo 'id->'.$sid[0].'<-';
    echo 'Вошли!';
}
```

p.s. Сам пытался набросать пару примеров авторизации, выходит только то, что сверху. Толи на статьи старые натыкаюсь, то ли что то не увидел

Comment: вам надо авторизовать сервер или клиента на вашем сайте?

Comment: клиента (логин и пасс от пользователя)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь авторизоваться на сервере? Тогда **причем тут API**? API, насколько я понимаю, предоставляет возможность авторизоваться на клиентской части, вызывая браузерное окно по своей ссылке, в котором он авторизуется, и дальше передает в скрипте вашей оболочке (сайту по js, переадресовывает по нужной вам ссылке, и т.д.), что пользователь авторищовался.

Но то что вы пытаетесь сделать - это авторизация напрямую, подставляя почту и пароль. В данном случае вам **надо просмотреть саму форму авторизации у контакта**, посмотреть какие параметры передаются. Возможно за этот код что-то изменилось, может они теперь добавлили какой-нибудь CSRF токен, и т.д.

Comment: Определения становятся более понятными, но если человеческим языком, то на определенном сайте хочу сделать авторизацию через ВК (да, я смотрел гуголь по этому запросу). Что то в роде дал ему 2 параметра, он вернул несколько переменных с данными пользователя. Больше в принципе и не надо

Comment: тогда вам не надо заморачиваться на счет логина и пароля (если вы не злоумышленник). Вечером постараюсь скинуть свои наработки.., а так, можете попробовать [uLogin][1]

[1]: http://ulogin.ru/constructor.php